# GoodData UI have issue in rendering Table type insights

Tags: reactjs, gooddata

I am using GoodData UI (version 8.0.0) **InsightView** component. It is working fine in rendering all types of Insights but **Table** type Insight is not rendering even at their [example: insightView-by-identifier](https://gdui-examples.herokuapp.com/insightView/insightView-by-identifier)
Any solution for it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Arvind, this issue has been fixed in the 8.1.x  branch, we would like to release 8.1.0  in the middle of November.

Comment: Hi,
In examples (https://gdui-examples.herokuapp.com/pivot-table) , PivotTable component is rendering but i am facing the issue in using it.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addCssClass' of undefined` 

Using gooddata ui version 8.1.0
Any help or codepen?